# grails how to iterate through params and set values

Tags: grails, groovy, parameters, loops

Is there anybody who has written a universal action for iterating through all params values and setting these values on an object?

I want to write something like this:

```
def updateSomeObject = {obj->
    for (def key : params.keySet()) {
        if (obj.hasProperty(key) != null) {
            def strValue = params[key]
            obj[key] = strValue
    }
}
```

but this works only for String values. In my case there are one to one associations, so it has to work with objects too.

I would like not to set properties (their names) to object, which values are null.

Comment: have you tried using ..metaclass.hasProperty()? obj."$key" = val?

Comment: I have tried after your post, but it gave the same result..problem in strVal, in one case it have to be int, for another property String or object..etc. Now it works only with String type.

Answer (score 3):

I use this to loop grails params:

```
Collection<?> keys = params.keySet()
    for (Object key : keys) {
        //check if key=action and key=controller which is grails default params
        if (!key.equals("action") && !key.equals("controller")) {
            println key //print out params-name
            println params.get(key) //print out params-value
        }
    }
```

Hope that help...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to bind request parameters to an object. You really shouldn't need to write your own code to do this, as the Grails controllers provide a [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) method that does this already.

Comment: Don please see one of my questions (title: update unidirectional one to one problem). bindData does not work, and I have to try something like this example...I ask this question, because I did not find my previous question answer.

Comment: Bella,Could you then refrase the relevant part of your previous question here. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you find an answer.

Comment: Ruben ok.In my previous question, I wrote, that I have 2 domain classes with unidirectional one to one association. class Domain1 { String val11 Domain2 domain2 } class Domain2 { String val21 } I could successfully create objects, but after association I could not update domain1 object. I have used obj.properties = params. After updating, When I want to save domain1, I got an exception: NullPointerException exception: ERROR gorm.SavePersistentMethod - Cannot get property 'class' on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'class' on null object at

Comment: I think exception throw, because it tries to update domain2 data in domain1, but it fails because domain2 = null

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
obj.properties = params
```

Hope that helps